# how to fill a List with two tables (one to one) relation c#

Tags: c#, database, data-structures

I have two Tables (Topic and Items) in an SQLite Database which have a one-to-one relationship.

```
Public class Topic
{
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
    public string Level;
    public List<Items> Data;
}

public class Items
{
    public Dictionary<string,string> Data;
}
```

the structure should be like this:

```
{
 "topics": [
  {
    "name": "English",
    "Description": "English",
    "Level": "English",
    "data": {
      "a": "a",
      "i": "i",
      "u": "u",
      "e": "e",
   }
}
```

My question is, how can I get the data from these two tables and store it in a list of topics?
I am using Ado.net, is there any other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your two tables?  Can you show the schema?

Comment: CREATE TABLE Items (
    TopicId INTEGER,
    [Key]   TEXT,
    Value   TEXT
);

Comment: CREATE TABLE Topic (
    Id             INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                           NOT NULL
                           UNIQUE
                           REFERENCES Items (TopicId),
    Name           TEXT,
    [Description;] TEXT,
    Level          TEXT
);